# Has no initializer, with Driver

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I don't understand why `Driver` (in RxSwift) complains about the initializer here:

```
class LoginVM
{
    let userName : Driver<String>?
    let password : Driver<String>?
}
```

I also tried the implicit unwrap, but the compiler says class `LoginVM` has no initializer. How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Does the answer below not answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Swift requires that `let` constants are always initialized by the time `init` finishes.  So you could either leave it as a `let` constant and set the value in `init`, or you can change it to a `var` and make it optional and only declare it.

**With `let`, initialized in `init`** (*Recommended*)

```
class LoginVM {
    let userName : Driver<String>

    init() {
        userName = Variable<String>("some initial string").asDriver()
    }
}
```

**With `Optional` `var`, only declared** (*Not Recommended*)

```
class LoginVM {
    var userName : Driver<String>?
}
```